# Best way to facilitate access to the results of specific queries only

Tags: mysql

I'm currently in the process of implementing a monitoring system, part of which includes monitoring certain aspects of a MySQL database, such as:

- The replication state of the given MySQL instance (sys table)
- The number of records in database 1's table x (db1.tableX)
- The sum total of a given attribute in another db's table (db2.tableY.column3)

These 3 things can be found using very simple queries:

```
SELECT viable_candidate FROM sys.gr_member_routing_candidate_status
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM db1.tableX
SELECT SUM(column3) FROM db2.tableY
```

However, this then requires a user account to be made with at least read access to 3 **entire databases / tables**.

Is there instead a way to limit access to the results of given queries **only**? I wondered about making an additional database which is somehow linked to the output of the above 3 queries, and then creating a new user with access only to this database, but I'm not sure what this technology is, or how it would work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You cant restrict upto query level. Lowest level you can go upto is column level in a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Create a view based on each query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html) and then [grant only a select permission to such view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html).

Example:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.view_name AS
SELECT viable_candidate 
FROM sys.gr_member_routing_candidate_status
```

And then

```
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.view_name TO 'user1'@'localhost'
```